# How can I make case-insentitive using spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<XEntity, Long> { 
Page<XEntity> findByParentIdAndNameContainingAndDescrContaining(Long parentId,String name, String descr, Pageable pageReq)
}
```

I'm writing. But it's case-sensitive. The result is wrong. How can I solve?

Comment: thank u, I put 'extends CrudRepository<CategoryEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CategoryEntity>'. this is working

Comment: `JpaSpecificationExecutor` doesn't have to do anything with case sensitivity

Comment: @Mansoor - it does, because `CriteriaBuilder` allows to transform `Path<String>` to upper|lower case using its `upper()` and `lower()` methods.

Comment: where is the OP calling those methods?

Answer (score 0):

Put IgnoreCase in the end of the method name.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write queries myself so I can better visualize what's going on.

```
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository<XEntity, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT xe from XEntity xe where xe.parentId = :parentId and xe.name like concat('%', :name, '%') and xe.description like concat('%', :descr, '%')")
    Page<XEntity> findByParentIdAndNameContainingAndDescrContaining(Long parentId,String name, String descr, Pageable pageReq)
}
```